# combine rows from table with NUM columns

Tags: mysql, row

I have this table:

```
Product | Qtdy | Price    
A       | NULL | 123.00    
A       | 23   | NULL
```

How Can I represent convert like that?

```
Product | Qtdy | Price    
A       | 23   | 123.00
```

Which means group by product using Null to return value print in the next line?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way.

```
SELECT Product, MAX(Qtdy), MAX(Price)
FROM table
GROUP BY Product
```

The better answer is to clean up your data so it isn't ditry.

Comment: Thanks danblack! Works well.